# Using estimators with tf xla.compile

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-xla

I am using some canned estimators provided by tensorflow such as DNN . 
The resulting model size are quite big (several hundred megabytes) and also latency are pretty high (hundreds of milliseconds). I want to try AOT compilation to see if i get serving latency improvements and model size reduction. Is there an example of how can i get xla.compile working with canned estimator . Can you point me to some example code or any one has similar experience guide me in the right direction ?

Comment: AFAIK you can only use autojit with estimators.

Comment: @pSoLT : any specific reason AOT compilation will not work with estimators ?